# qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly KEYEXPIRED while updating QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to update QGIS 3 (2.99) today using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I get an error complaining about the keys expired. The Error message is:

```
Err:8 http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial InRelease                 
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973

...

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973
W: Failed to fetch http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973  KEYEXPIRED 1502999973
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to `add-key` again from the server as follows:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 089EBE08314DF160
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 073D307A618E5811
```

But the error remains.

Any suggestion on how to fix the error?

Also, if really the keys expired as suggested, do I need to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu to find the new QGIS key for 2017:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
```

Since the old key(s) is/are expired, you can safely delete it/them.

The new key expires 2019-08-16, but a new one will certainly be created until then.